# How to delete a multiple record using check box in ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am beginner to ror. In my ror application I used scaffold function with one field, I just add a check box feature. Now I am try to do select a multiple check box (of records) and delete that records from the table.
While I click the delete button I got a Routing Error. Please help me to rectify my error.

Here is my Controller.rb file:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /messages
  # GET /messages.json
  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  # GET /messages/1
  # GET /messages/1.json
  def show
     # @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /messages/new
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  # GET /messages/1/edit
  def edit
     # @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /messages
  # POST /messages.json
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /messages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /messages/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.update(message_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @message }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /messages/1
  # DELETE /messages/1.json
  def destroy
    @message.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to messages_url, notice: 'Message was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_message
      @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

Here is index.html.erb file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Messages</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
    <%= form_tag messages_path, :method => 'delete' do %>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]", message.id %></td>
        <td><%= message.content %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
       <!--  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td> -->
      </tr>
    <% end %>     
  </tbody>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_to 'Delete', messages_path %>
</table>

<br>
<%= link_to  'New Message', new_message_path %> 
</br>
```

My Routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages do
    collection {post :destroy}      
  end
  root to: "messages#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

ERROR SHOWN:

> Routing Error No route matches [DELETE] "/messages"

Answer (score 0):

:)

Can you edit routes.rb like this :

```
resources :message
```

Instead of your :

```
  resources :messages do
    collection {post :destroy}      
  end
```

The HTTP Method for destroy is 'DELETE', not 'POST'.

If you run 'rails routes' you must see a line like :

```
DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Destiny. After I change the routes.rb file, I got a following while run the server    **  ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Messages#index  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"message"}, missing required keys: [:id] **

Comment: Can you post your entire routes.rb file?
Thanks !

Comment: I already post my entire routes.rb file. That  is the entire file

Comment: `<td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>`

It's `message_path(message.id)`

You can see all routes helpers in `rails routes`

Can you print it here in real answer? (not comment)